# specify fields in zf2 doctrine2 query

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework2

How do we specify fields to return in the result, in zend framework 2 using doctrine 2?
Here is my query:

```
$allLanguages = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository('Language')
                    ->findAll();
```

I just want 'name' field in the result from languages table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use DQL like this to customize query.

```
    $u = $_GET['u'];
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT u.username FROM Auth\Entity\User u WHERE u.username LIKE :username AND u.companyID = :companyID ");
    $query->setParameter('username', '%'.$u.'%')
            ->setParameter('companyID', $companyID);

    $users = $query->getResult();
```

In your case above. It can be somehting like.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT l.name FROM Langauge l");

$langaugeNames = $query->getResult();
```

[Doctrine Query Language DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

[Query Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: I was looking for a way to not use DQL, and instead pass arguments in what I have implemented (as shown in my example), but I guess I might need to use DQL anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use DQL directly:

```
$languages = $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT l.name FROM Language l")->getResult();
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results